# How to inject security context authentication into custom ConstraintValidator?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, nullpointerexception, spring-webflux

In Kotlin using Spring Boot 3 and WebFlux I have this custom validator that needs two inputs: one is the value that being validated, but I also need the authentication principal to validate if the user has legit access to the value.

I get a `NullPointerException` when using `getContext()`.

```kotlin
@Component
class OrgInstanceValidator(val validator: OrgPermissionValidator) : ConstraintValidator<ValidOrgInstance, InstanceId> {

    override fun isValid(value: InstanceId, context: ConstraintValidatorContext): Boolean = runBlocking {
        val accessToken = ReactiveSecurityContextHolder.getContext().map(SecurityContext::getAuthentication).map {
            it.principal as Jwt
        }.awaitSingle()
        validator.validateInstanceAccess(accessToken.subject, value).awaitSingle()
    }.isGranted
}
```

I would also accept using AOP on the controllers, value is a `PathParam` in this example.

Anybody have experience solving this?

Using `ReactiveSecurityContextHolder` doesn't seem to work, and lowering the bean precedence doesn't work either.

Comment: have you tried accessing the `ReactiveSecurityContextHolder` the regular `SecurityContextHolder`stores the principal in `ThreadLocal`which means it doesn't work in reactive applications, the other uses the reactive context to store the `Principal`

Comment: @Toerktumlare I tried ReactiveSecurityContextHolder and I'm still getting NPE. I'll update the description.

Answer (score 1):

We gave up on trying to use ConstraintValidator on a reactive/Webflux configuration.

We ended up using the same mechanism used by most RestController annotations like AuthenticationPrincipal, PathVariable and so on, by creating our own annotations and creating beans for HandlerMethodArgumentResolver types that handle the annotation class:

```kotlin
import org.springframework.web.reactive.HandlerMapping.URI_TEMPLATE_VARIABLES_ATTRIBUTE
import java.security.Principal
...

class MethodAnnotationValidator<T : Annotation>(
    adapterRegistry: ReactiveAdapterRegistry,
    private val annotation: Class<T>,
    private val validator: (Principal, String) -> Mono<Any>,
) : HandlerMethodArgumentResolver {

    // compose this resolver to fetch the Auth context
    private val principal = PrincipalMethodArgumentResolver(adapterRegistry)

    // path var resolver isn't composable, next best thing
    private val pathParam = { paramName: String, exchange: ServerWebExchange -> exchange
        .getAttributeOrDefault(URI_TEMPLATE_VARIABLES_ATTRIBUTE, emptyMap<Any, Any>())
        .get(paramName)!!}
    
   // resolve Principal and PathParam and call validator() 
   // inside resolveArgument() override
...
```